# Find if value is undefined of multiple keys in object

Tags: javascript

I would like to detect if some values are not defined in an object with several properties

for example :

```
let test = {
    helo: undefined,
    hey: "not undefined"
}
```

i tried this :

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

but if possible, I don't want to use a for loop, I would like a boolean result in return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be looking for something like this.

```js
const test = {
    helo: undefined,
    hey: "not undefined"
};

const some_undefined = Object.values(test).some(v => v === undefined);

console.log(some_undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for that :

```
const hasOneKeyUndefined = (object)=>
{
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
      if (value === undefined) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
const test = {
    helo: undefined,
    hey: "not undefined"
};
Object.keys(test).map((key, idx) => test[key] === undefined)
```